# Azure devops build push image to aks

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am trying to configure release pipeline in Azure Devops to push image to registry. In the release pipeline I have two tasks run service and expose deployment. When there is no service and deployment in AKS or on first code checkin it works fine but on next checkin it fails service already exist. 
Any idea where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: I have added two tasks deploy to kubernetes in release pipeline . 1st one actual command is RUN to create deployment . Second one to EXPOSE deployement as a service .

Comment: Kubectl run deploymentname --image  --port.                                         Kubectl expose deployment deploymentname --type =loadbalancer --port 80 --targetport 8090  --name service name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be using yaml files and `kubectl apply`. what you are doing is an imperative way of managing resource and `kubectl apply` would give you a declarative way of doing that, so it would only apply changes. But given that you only need to update the image, it will probably make more sense to do `kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1` , so use `kubectl set image` to update the image on the existing deployment. another option would be to use something like [flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux) to manage images

Comment: Okay so you mean 1st time or on very first checkin i have to run and expose after that i should disable these two tasks and just use set image task ?

Comment: One more thing can i use yaml files for this ? I am having external gitlab repository and only want to comfigure it here . So is there any option of yaml files for external gitlab repository ?

Comment: no, just run `kubectl apply` each time and them run `kubectl set`. you can use yaml files in external repo if you first download it

Comment: Kibectl set image command showing error server doesnt have resource deployment/nginx-deployment . Can you please name attiributes to put in kubectl set command ? Like after kubectl set image <container-name or deployment name> ?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#updating-resources

Comment: One more thing i wanna ask  i have to do further configuration to access it through public ip address ? Because when i try to open it through its public ip it doesnt respond

Comment: please create a new question for this and share the link, I'll look into that

Comment: kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1 
on using this command error :  resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified

Comment: please, create a new question :) if you are referring to existing answer you need to adjust it to match your configuration